# O código não funciona da maneira esperada. (python e kivy)

Tags: python, kivy

Eu não consigo mudar o nome do Label 1 nem do Label 2, através da função ''click''. O programa mostra apenas o "oi" no console.

Código python:

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.9.1")
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class MinhaTela(BoxLayout):
    def click(self):
        print("oi")
        self.ids.lb1.text: ""
        self.ids.lb2.text: "10"


class Estudo(App):
    pass


e1 = Estudo()
e1.run()
```

Código kivy:

```
<MinhaTela@BoxLayout>
orientation: "vertical"

Button:
    text: "OK"
    on_press: root.click()
Label:
    text: "Label 1"
    id: lb1
Label:
    text: "Label 2"
    id: lb2

MinhaTela:
```

Answer (score 0):

Tem que usar o sinal igual em vez dos dois pontos.

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.9.1")
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class MinhaTela(BoxLayout):
    def click(self):
        print("oi")
        self.ids.lb1.text = ""
        self.ids.lb2.text = "10"


class EstudoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MinhaTela()


e1 = EstudoApp()
e1.run()
```